# Plot a curve rather than a line

Tags: matlab, plot

In matlab, I have a vector, say `x` and a function of `x` say `y`. I want to plot `x` and `y` in matlab.

The problem is I want smooth curve (not in a sense of smooth texture but differentiable, and without sharp bends). Matlab, with plot, simply joins the points and the plotted curve has sharp bends.

Is there a way I can resolve this?

Comment: you need to interpolate, look at the interp1 function with `'cubic'`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html. Note that `'spline'` will have a continuous first and second derivative, `'cubic'` might give you a better looking curve but will have a discontinuous second derivative but I think that sounds acceptable for what you're after

Comment: Plot more points. It's hard to say anything more specific about problems you may be having without seeing any code

Comment: @Dan Thanks! Will have a look at it.  and to: wakjah, this is not problem specific. due to computation time limit, taking many points is not possible (consider nested loops).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967951/plot-a-curve-rather-than-a-line/15969551#comment22759105_15967951) and [wakjah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967951/plot-a-curve-rather-than-a-line/15969551#comment22759111_15967951), what you need is to interpolate `x` and `y` to more sample points

```
plot( x, y, '+r' ); % plot the original points
n = numel(x); % number of original points
xi = interp1( 1:n, x, linspace(1, n, 10*n) ); % new sample points 
yi = interp1(   x, y, xi );
hold all;
plot( xi, yi ); % should be smooth between the original points
```