# Simple curve fitting

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have 2 vectors

```
x = [ -11.1821  -9.8248  -8.4675  -7.1101  -5.7528 -4.3955  -3.0382  -1.6808  -0.3235  1.0338  2.3912  3.7485 ]

y = [ 0   0   0   0   0   0   7   1   0   0   0   0 ]
```

which are histogram data.

I tried `interp1` and `spline` methods to draw a curve instead on connecting the points with lines, but the first one connects points by lines and the second one goes to negative values, which make no sense in a histogram.

Is there any simple way how I can overlay the data with a curve ? I don't have the curve fitting toolbox.

EDIT: I cannot use `histfit` even though it's histogram data. The bin count has to be created manually.

Comment: Do you have raw data instead of hist data?

Comment: Yes, but there is a background hist distributions and I need to utilize the bins that are there. Say I am adding 4 additional data sets utilizing the hist bins set up by the background distribution.

Comment: Could you share the code where you are trying to interpolate.

Comment: I progressed according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967951/plot-a-curve-rather-than-a-line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

When fitting a curve to histogram data, you can avoid interpolating into negative values (as `spline` does) by utilizing either the `'pchip'` or `'cubic'` option.

```
xi = interp1(1:n,x,linspace(1,n,10*n));
yi = interp1(x,y,xi,'pchip');
plot(xi,yi)
```

Hope this helps someone out there.